# Why doesn't the U.S. government cancel at least some existing work visas to decrease unemployment?

Tags: united-states, immigration, employment

The U.S. economy is suffering from an unprecedented crisis/pandemic/unemployment. The American people need jobs right now. And still there are like 1 million or so foreign workers, temp workers, H1B, J1, whatever...

I don't understand WHY doesn't the U.S. government cancel at least some of those visas???

---

Below I would like to comment on some possible counterarguments:

1. Some people may argue that those foreign workers are "highly skilled". But I beg to differ. I work in one of the biggest U.S. companies (like Apple and Google). Everyday I deal with a lot of foreign workers on H1B visa, and other work visas. And I know for a fact a lot of them could easily be replaced with fresh U.S. graduates. Most of H1B visa guys don't have any special skills. I mean they might be smart but definitely not irreplaceable.
2. Other people may argue that employers choose to hire foreign workers to reduce the costs. But again I beg to differ. In the current economy, I believe highly skilled U.S. citizens won't bargain for a higher paycheck.

PARADOX: I know lot of H1B workers who got cushy positions, but don't produce any real value. Most of them are on "support" roles, like analytics, finance etc. It blows my mind when I see smart U.S. graduates not being able to get a job. There are millions of smart and talented U.S. citizens with Bachelors' degrees and a huge student loan who are not able to get a simple developer or analyst job....I know this for a fact.

---

**What I'm proposing is this:
The U.S. government to issue an order to cancel all H1B, J1 etc. visas. Not suspend, but cancel effective immediately. Of course employers will have  an opportunity to petition to extend visas for some "super special" employees. If a H1B worker is so "valuable", then the employer may file a one page petition, explaining the extraordinary qualities. But I know for a fact that most employers will easily find a U.S. citizen as a replacement.**

Please correct me this sounds unreasonable.

Comment: You understand that this does not change unemployment at all. It simply displaces it to another country, so the world is no better off than before. It likely worsens unemployment, in fact, because not every position thus freed will be immediately filled. Not every person with a canceled work visa will have to leave, either, so that's more unemployment you have created.

Comment: Also, why would you want "smart US graduates" to get jobs that, according to you, do not produce value? That sounds like a waste to me.

Comment: This seems more like a policy proposal or discussion prompt than a question, in which case it would be off-topic

Comment: @divibisan IMO this is salvageable and could be on-topic, especially should it be reworded without the extraneous subjective characterizations...  For example, Trump has shown an interest in restricting visas such as H-1B.  This was published a few weeks ago, for example:  [**Trump set to announce new restrictions on H-1B visa program for foreign workers**](https://fortune.com/2020/06/21/trump-h1b-visa-program-restrictions/)  Offhand, I don't know if there has been any action on such restrictions, though.

Comment: @JustMe I think you’re probably right, but I don’t want to make such major changes to the question if that’s not what the OP wanted to do here. If they want to make it on-topic, I think you have good advice. I’d say if the body of the question asked the question in the title in a neutral way, it’d be upvote worthy.

Comment: The plain fact is that there simply aren't enough "fresh U.S. graduates" to fill the positions.  Even leaving out the matter of experience (few fresh graduates, US or other, can really step into a job and immediately be productive), US grads in STEM fields are pretty well spoken for already - and a large share of those grads are international students anyway :-)  In addition, much of the unemployment is in service jobs of the sort that require personal contact.  Most people with STEM jobs - the sort that most H1b workers fill - can easily work from home.

Answer (score 3):

[According to the US Department of Labor](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/immigration/h1b):

> The intent of the H-1B provisions is to help **employers who cannot otherwise obtain needed business skills and abilities from the U.S. workforce** by authorizing the temporary employment of qualified individuals who are not otherwise authorized to work in the United States.

> **The law establishes certain standards in order to protect similarly employed U.S. workers from being adversely affected** by the employment of the nonimmigrant workers, as well as to protect the H-1B nonimmigrant workers. Employers must attest to the Department of Labor that they will pay **wages** to the H-1B nonimmigrant workers that **are at least equal** to the actual wage paid by the employer to other workers with similar experience and qualifications for the job in question, or the prevailing wage for the occupation in the area of intended employment – whichever is greater.

Therefore, if we assume that this policy works as intended, revoking it may not have the effect you intend. Rather, it is more likely that the jobs will remain unfilled, or that employers will have to settle for less qualified candidates. For just one case in point look what happened [when Alabama tried to crack down on undocumented migrants](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/oct/14/alabama-immigration-law-workers). Efforts to fill those jobs with unemployed US citizens overwhelmingly failed and crops rotted in the fields.

There may be other reasons this is a bad idea. Even if it is legal, it may be perceived as a breach of contract in countries like India that send skilled workers. If you accept that H2B has any benefit whatsoever (if only in good times) this may make it harder to attract more workers in the future.

Comment: Another reason that it might be a bad idea is that it would make hundreds of thousands of people unemployed and possibly forced to leave their communities for no other reason other than that, as non-Americans, they apparently don't deserve their jobs.

Comment: @Obie2.0 It's a fair point but 1) I don't expect the OP is inclined to agree 2) it's clearly not the primary purpose of the visa program to benefit non-US citizens, many of whom I imagine would much prefer to remain in their native countries in the first place if they could earn a reasonable income there.

Comment: *"Efforts to fill those jobs with unemployed US citizens overwhelmingly failed"* - did they actually try improving pay and conditions, or just fill those jobs at the old foreign standards of pay and conditions?

Comment: @Steve - seemingly not, since the linked article ends quoting the farmer: "It's going to be a little while, but eventually people will see what has been done here. The cost of food in the supermarkets is going to go up, and in the end we will all pay the price." He also reports firing a US citizen couple who briefly joined his workforce but falsely tallied their harvest so as to double their wages.

Comment: @TomGoodfellow, agreed. It seems to suggest that he could indeed attract locals, but they'd want at least twice the current rate of pay.